# RuntimeError: For unbatched 2-D input, hx and cx should also be 2-D but got (3-D, 3-D) tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error, lstm

hey I have some problems with my LSTM. I have 6 features and I´m sending all my data (29002 rows) in the LSTM at once (is this a good idea?).

My Input is of size:

Training Shape torch.Size([290002, 1, 6]) torch.Size([290002, 1])

Testing Shape torch.Size([74998, 1, 6]) torch.Size([74998, 1])

my model:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, hidden_dim_LSTM, num_layers_LSTM, hidden1, drop):
    super(LSTM, self).__init__()
    
    self.hidden_dim_LSTM = hidden_dim_LSTM
    self.num_layers_LSTM = num_layers_LSTM
    self.hidden1=hidden1
    self.drop=drop
    
    final_output_dim = 1

    #self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim, self.num_layers, batch_first=True)
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(6, hidden_size=hidden_dim_LSTM, num_layers=num_layers_LSTM, batch_first=True)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_dim_LSTM, out_features=hidden1)
    self.drop = nn.Dropout(drop)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden1, out_features=final_output_dim) 

    
def forward(self, x):
    h_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers_LSTM, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim_LSTM)).requires_grad_().to(device) #hidden state
    c_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers_LSTM, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim_LSTM)).requires_grad_().to(device) #internal state
    # Propagate input through LSTM
    output, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0)) #lstm with input, hidden, and internal state
    hn = hn.view(-1, self.hidden_dim_LSTM) #reshaping the data for Dense layer next
    out = F.relu(hn)
    out = self.fc1(out) 
    out = self.drop(out)
    out = torch.relu(out) 
    #out = self.drop(out)
    out = self.fc2(out) 
    return out
```

When I start the training I get this Error:
RuntimeError: For unbatched 2-D input, hx and cx should also be 2-D but got (3-D, 3-D) tensors
at Line: output, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0))

I'm grateful for every help!

Comment: From the pytorch docs: `h_0: tensor of shape (D * \text{num\_layers}, H_{out})(D∗num_layers,H out) for unbatched input or (D * \text{num\_layers}, N, H_{out})(D∗num_layers,N,H out) containing the initial hidden state for each element in the input sequence. Defaults to zeros if (h_0, c_0) is not provided.`. Therefore, your inputs aren't batched (which is in your error function). What is `x.size()` at the start of your forward call? It should be `[L,N,F]` (L - length, N - batch size, F - feature size).

Comment: x.size() is: torch.Size([290002, 1, 6]) so do i have to remove one dimension from h0 ? In this case i get the same error with 3-D but got 2-D .. ? or do i only need 2-D input for unbatched LSTM ?

Comment: Your sequence has 290002 steps? That's huge! Either way, your size allocation is wrong. It should be of shape `[self.num_layers_LSTM, self.hidden_dim_LSTM]` because h0 and c0 do not have a time dimension.

Comment: with the shape: [self.num_layers_LSTM, self.hidden_dim_LSTM] 
I get the error: RuntimeError: For batched 3-D input, hx and cx should also be 3-D but got (2-D, 2-D) tensors
in line: 24 output, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0))

Comment: now I changed the input to: torch.Size([290002, 6]) and it seams to work just real slow. And I got: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([290002, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 1])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)